# Opinions about Dabo

Tags: python, dabo

Has anyone used Dabo lately? How does it rate vs Boa Constructor, etc? I'm writing a new Python database app and Dabo looks promising, but what's the real-world scoop on it?

Is it used by many developers? It's not talked about very much here on SO, or anywhere, as far as I can tell. I'm just a little concerned that the support community might be too small, or the possibility that writers might decide to throw in the towel.

What is your assessment of Dabo?

Answer (score 1):

One of the authors of Dabo recently wrote some information about Dabos userbase at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417/anyone-used-dabo-for-a-medium-big-project/106464#106464).

But for the rest of your question I am not of great help.

Answer (score 1):

All I can give you are some videos made by the author on pycon 2007 (I fell in love with the framework with his presentation(but I don't have any experience yet(working on it though)))

**[Ed Leafe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19399/ed-leafe) PyCon 2007 presentation entitled "Developing Desktop Applications in Dabo:**

- [Dabo PyCon 2007 - Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3En1LFmryQ)
- [Dabo PyCon 2007 - Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UYK7Nsogdk)
- [Dabo PyCon 2007 - Part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNcynb3Ut84)
- [Dabo PyCon 2007 - Part 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8G8AefXDo8)
- [Dabo PyCon 2007 - Part 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wen8Cs-XEHg)
- [Dabo PyCon 2007 - Part 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnreuZwa1LE)

If anyone have more videos please put it in the comments and I'll add them to the answers (or if you're powerfull enough, just add it :) )

Comment: How to recognize a lisp programmer